# Run program (exe) as different user (service account), access to network share

Tags: c#, console-application, dllimport

From couple of days I'm strugling with problem. I must write a small application which runs another app with different credentials (service account). Everything is easy but on the server we have a policy that denies log on service accounts and the policy can't be removed.

I tried:
Process class,
Impersonating mechanism,
CreateProcessWithLogonW,
CreateProcessAsUser

with different configurations. Once I managed to log on with service account I have error network path not found.

CreateProcessWithLogonW works perfectly on local machine but not on the server where this policy is. Maybe I'm missing some certain configuration.

Comment: having to use a network path is usually a problem. No viable alternatives? ie an ftp server for example?

Comment: Nope changing infrastructure is not an option. Funny thing is that when i run this program from windows scheduler using this service account there is no problem with paths.

Comment: is the share mapped with a driver letter ( ie X:\ ) or with \\server\folder?

Comment: With \\server\folder.

Comment: and what about creating a windows service containing your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got solution. This was configuration problem. Server didn't have proper DNS entries for DFS (Distributed File System).